# psycopg2: copy_expert csv file containing e+ integer number

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2

First, let me show how to reproduce the problem. It's simple setup.

here is my simple test csv file

```
a;b
1;1
0;2
1.5637e+07;3
```

the test csv file is generated by pandas dataframe's to_csv method

```
import csv, pandas as pd

d = {'a' : pd.Series([1, 0.0, 1.5637e+07]),'b' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df_csv = df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding="utf-8", index=False,
                   sep=';', quotechar='"', float_format="%g", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

then, let's create a test table in db

```
create table testtb (
    a integer,
    b integer
)
```

Finally, I tried to export the csv file into that table, some set up code here

```
def parse_column(header):
    column_str = ",".join(header[0].split(";"))
    return column_str

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test1 " +
                            " user=postgres" +
                            " host=localhost" +
                            " password=password")

cur = conn.cursor()

with open('test.csv', "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    f.seek(0)

    copy_sql = """
            COPY {}.{}({}) FROM STDIN CSV HEADER DELIMITER ';'
            """.format("public", "simplew", parse_column(header))
    cur.copy_expert(sql=copy_sql, file=f)

conn.commit()
```

The problem is, now I get

```
invalid input syntax for integer: "1.5637e+07"
```

There are few constraints for solution here

1. I can't use to_sql method of dataframe, I am doing bulk copying here, to_sql is too slow..
2. because of No.1, I have to follow the procedure I laid out above, to_csv, then copy the csv to DB, which means I can't use any code to format "1.5637e+07", except setting float_format in the to_csv method..
3. about the float_format, I need to get rid of trailing zero of float number, so I set it to %g currently

Finally, I get the input dataframe this way:

```
df = DataFrame.from_records(list(  my_api_call()   ))
```

the example I made up above was just to show the case

Comment: What is the problem with using [`df.to_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)? It will take care of everything for you, instead of that roundabout way you are using. Also, why are you assigning `df.to_csv` to a variable?

Comment: @Kartik sorry, forget to mention, can't use to_sql method of dataframe, doing bulk copying here, to_sql is too slow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.5637e+07` isn't an integer. It's a float

```
>>> 1.5637e+07
15637000.0
>>> type(1.5637e+07)
<class 'float'>
```

If you want an integer, just do `15637*10**3` or simply `15637000`. That will be an integer.

```
pd.Series([1, 0.0, 15637000])
```

Note: doing `int(1.5637e+07)` would also work here, but would fail with loss of precision for highest 10th powers: (`int(1.5637e+22) = 15637000000000000786432`) so better stick to integer exponentiation, unlike C integers, python integers can handle unlimited values, well memory-limited at most)

Comment: You cleared one point of confusion for me (that number is float). I just update the question to add in a few constraints. If you could update the answer, I would accept it as the best:)

Comment: :) let me tell you that I learned about integer exponentation in python only a year ago. Before I was just doing stupid `int(1.5637e+07)`. But `int(1.5637e+22) = 15637000000000000786432`

Comment: thanks for your effort, but sadly, I am getting those data through api call, and can't do int() to convert them...

Comment: thanks for accepting, but I'm not quite satisfied: I won't accept your acceptance :) You mean `test.csv` isn't yours to create right? that's very fixable you know. I'm not getting the "API call" part. Your reproducer creates a file and then reads it. What's the real case?

Comment: haha, let's see whether we can figure this out.   I get the dataframe this way:    df = DataFrame.from_records(list(  my_api_call()   ))

Comment: I want to find a format that could achieve:   1.0 -> 1  and 9.87e+7 -> 98700000

Comment: could you just tell me what `my_api_call()` returns (a simplified example). Is it a python list, an iterable? can you post an example of that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128365/discussion-between-user2628641-and-jean-francois-fabre).